# How can I align, break and fill tabular entries properly for my Curriculum Vitae?

Tags: tables, supertabular

I am trying to make a nice Curriculum Vitae in LaTeX but am having some difficulties with aligning, breaking and filling the tabular entries.

A Curriculum Vitae has to be short and clear. I thus need a tabular environment which is allowed to be split across multiple pages. The 'entries' of the tabular environment have to be horizontally aligned, but should not be split. For instance, if we consider the following

```
\section*{Work experience}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Starting date 1 - End date 1 & Name 1\\
        & Description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1\\
        \\
        Starting date 2 - End date 2 & Name 2\\
        & Description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2\\
        \\
    \end{tabular}
```

, I want the descriptions to be limited to the page width minus its horizontal offset, and I do not want the descriptions to be split across multiple pages. Splitting should only be allowed between 'entry 1' and 'entry 2'.

For the former, you can use `\usepackage{tabularx}` and for the latter the `\usepackage{supertabular}` could perhaps help. However, I do not know how to use them at the same time, and supertabular break at every `\\` and not only between 'entry 1' and 'entry 2'.

How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: You can use p{} instead of l, but you will have to manualy adjust the width of the column to fit the page.  This is equivalent to putting a \parbox into the column.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the tip, but I have to use it a lot, so doing it manually is not an option. Besides that, it does not solve the splitting problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `tabularx` span over multiple pages using the `ltablex` package, which is based on `longtable`. Simply importing the package is enough - then you can just use tabularx and your table will span over multiple pages (see: [Tabularx: Break long tables over several pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376790/tabularx-break-long-tables-over-several-pages/376804)).

To disallow a pagebreak at the end of a row you use `\\*` instead of `\\`, as described on Page 9 in the [longtable manual](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf).

In your example it would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}
    \section*{Work experience}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l | X }
        Starting date 1 - End date 1 & Name 1\\*
        & Description 1 description 1 description 1 description 1 ... \\
        \\
        Starting date 2 - End date 2 & Name 2\\*
        & Description 2 description 2 description 2 description 2 ... \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just realised now, that this question is 6 years old. I hope it still helps someone...