# Tabularx: Break long tables over several pages

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, tabularx, fullpage

I am making a long table for my thesis correction. It will be a really long table and here is what I have till now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}


    \begin{document}

    This document is a list of changes made according to the requests for both examiners. Texts in black are the requested items from examiners, while texts in \textcolor{blue}{blue} are the amened items. Pages refer to the page number on which these requested items are in both the original document and \textcolor{blue}{amended document}.\\
    \newline
    \newline
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c | X }


    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Changes Required from Examiner A}} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \textbf{\textit{page}} & \textbf{\textit{Content}} \\
    \hline

       i & A good English speaker should look at the title, the Abstract, and Introduction and eliminate any
    elementary mistakes of no/definite/indefinite article, subject/verb agreement.\\
    & \\
       \textcolor{blue}{i} & \textcolor{blue}{All grammar has been checked.} \\
       & \\
    \hline

    N/A & The candidate should consider all titles of sections that are uninformative to any other reader, such as 4.2 Test WaveFlume, 4.3 Test Fiel\_H5\_T10, 4.4 Test Field\_IHFOAM, 4.5 Test Field\_Extend, 4.6
    Test Field\_H2\_T20, 5.1 Test\_SHORELINE. They are all meaningless, except to the person who has
    done the work. I strongly suggest something like “Flat bed, single water layer", "Flat bed, water
    layer and air layer", and so on.   \\
    & \\
     \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:
    3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , 
    3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,
    3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,
    3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,
    3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , 
    4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,
    4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , 
    4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,
    4.2.1
    Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,
    4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,
    4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity.} \\
    & \\   
    \hline    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is
    ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \hline
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    

    \end{tabularx}

    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

And the final product
[image]

Is there anyway to break this table automatically at the end of a page and continue onto the next page, when the current page is full?

Comment: Why don't use the `longtable`package instead? In my experience it can works better for a table like this.

Comment: @Aradnix I want to have all text wrap inside the table automatically as well

Comment: @Aradnix longtable does not have a X column.

Comment: You could use longtable instead but I would not use a table at all here I would use a list with a fixed labelwidth, that is much simpler and has the advantage that long items can break at the end of the page, table based solutions typically only break between items.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to use tabularx inside a longtable environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106452/is-it-possible-to-use-tabularx-inside-a-longtable-environment), [How to create a table that spans over multiple pages, breaking single rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43068/how-to-create-a-table-that-spans-over-multiple-pages-breaking-single-rows), [how to create table in continued on next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335971/), [Combining tabularx, sidewaystable and longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345382/)

Answer (score 32):

You cannot use the `longtable` package if you want to preserve the `X` column. Therefore you could use `ltablex`.

[image: ltablex]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{color}


    \begin{document}

    This document is a list of changes made according to the requests for both examiners. Texts in black are the requested items from examiners, while texts in \textcolor{blue}{blue} are the amened items. Pages refer to the page number on which these requested items are in both the original document and \textcolor{blue}{amended document}.\\
    \newline
    \newline
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c | X }


    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Changes Required from Examiner A}} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \textbf{\textit{page}} & \textbf{\textit{Content}} \\
    \hline

       i & A good English speaker should look at the title, the Abstract, and Introduction and eliminate any
    elementary mistakes of no/definite/indefinite article, subject/verb agreement.\\
    & \\
       \textcolor{blue}{i} & \textcolor{blue}{All grammar has been checked.} \\
       & \\
    \hline

    N/A & The candidate should consider all titles of sections that are uninformative to any other reader, such as 4.2 Test WaveFlume, 4.3 Test Fiel\_H5\_T10, 4.4 Test Field\_IHFOAM, 4.5 Test Field\_Extend, 4.6
    Test Field\_H2\_T20, 5.1 Test\_SHORELINE. They are all meaningless, except to the person who has
    done the work. I strongly suggest something like “Flat bed, single water layer", "Flat bed, water
    layer and air layer", and so on.   \\
    & \\
     \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:
    3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , 
    3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,
    3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,
    3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,
    3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , 
    4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,
    4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , 
    4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,
    4.2.1
    Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,
    4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,
    4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity.} \\
    & \\   
    \hline    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is
    ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \hline
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    
       i & A good English speaker should look at the title, the Abstract, and Introduction and eliminate any
    elementary mistakes of no/definite/indefinite article, subject/verb agreement.\\
    & \\
       \textcolor{blue}{i} & \textcolor{blue}{All grammar has been checked.} \\
       & \\
    \hline

    N/A & The candidate should consider all titles of sections that are uninformative to any other reader, such as 4.2 Test WaveFlume, 4.3 Test Fiel\_H5\_T10, 4.4 Test Field\_IHFOAM, 4.5 Test Field\_Extend, 4.6
    Test Field\_H2\_T20, 5.1 Test\_SHORELINE. They are all meaningless, except to the person who has
    done the work. I strongly suggest something like “Flat bed, single water layer", "Flat bed, water
    layer and air layer", and so on.   \\
    & \\
     \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:
    3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , 
    3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,
    3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,
    3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,
    3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , 
    4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,
    4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , 
    4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,
    4.2.1
    Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,
    4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,
    4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity.} \\
    & \\   
    \hline    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is
    ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \hline
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    

    \end{tabularx}

    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

---

But you may also consider using `booktabs` in addition and make your table look nice.

[image: better style]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}


    \begin{document}

    This document is a list of changes made according to the requests for both examiners. Texts in black are the requested items from examiners, while texts in \textcolor{blue}{blue} are the amened items. Pages refer to the page number on which these requested items are in both the original document and \textcolor{blue}{amended document}.\par
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X }
    \caption{Changes Required from Examiner A}\\\toprule\endfirsthead
    \toprule\endhead
    \midrule\multicolumn{2}{r}{\itshape continues on next page}\\\midrule\endfoot
    \bottomrule\endlastfoot
    \textbf{page} & \textbf{Content} \\\midrule

       i & A good English speaker should look at the title, the Abstract, and Introduction and eliminate any
    elementary mistakes of no/definite/indefinite article, subject/verb agreement.\\
    & \\
       \textcolor{blue}{i} & \textcolor{blue}{All grammar has been checked.} \\
       & \\
    \midrule

    N/A & The candidate should consider all titles of sections that are uninformative to any other reader, such as 4.2 Test WaveFlume, 4.3 Test Fiel\_H5\_T10, 4.4 Test Field\_IHFOAM, 4.5 Test Field\_Extend, 4.6
    Test Field\_H2\_T20, 5.1 Test\_SHORELINE. They are all meaningless, except to the person who has
    done the work. I strongly suggest something like “Flat bed, single water layer", "Flat bed, water
    layer and air layer", and so on.   \\
    & \\
     \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:
    3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , 
    3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,
    3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,
    3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,
    3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , 
    4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,
    4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , 
    4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,
    4.2.1
    Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,
    4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,
    4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity.} \\
    & \\   
    \midrule    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is
    ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \midrule
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    
       i & A good English speaker should look at the title, the Abstract, and Introduction and eliminate any
    elementary mistakes of no/definite/indefinite article, subject/verb agreement.\\
    & \\
       \textcolor{blue}{i} & \textcolor{blue}{All grammar has been checked.} \\
       & \\
    \midrule

    N/A & The candidate should consider all titles of sections that are uninformative to any other reader, such as 4.2 Test WaveFlume, 4.3 Test Fiel\_H5\_T10, 4.4 Test Field\_IHFOAM, 4.5 Test Field\_Extend, 4.6
    Test Field\_H2\_T20, 5.1 Test\_SHORELINE. They are all meaningless, except to the person who has
    done the work. I strongly suggest something like “Flat bed, single water layer", "Flat bed, water
    layer and air layer", and so on.   \\
    & \\
     \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:
    3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , 
    3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,
    3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,
    3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,
    3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , 
    4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,
    4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , 
    4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,
    4.2.1
    Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,
    4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,
    4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity.} \\
    & \\   
    \midrule    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is
    ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \midrule
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: A note of caution to some users: using multicolumn will wreck the rendering, so remove them before shifting to the ltablex environment

Comment: @Kim How does it happen for you? Have you recompiled often enough?

Comment: `ltablex` changes the behaviour of `tabularx`: it no longer accepts an `itemize` in a cell.

Comment: @dremoradis Are you sure? `ltablex` should behave as longtable does…

Answer (score 10):

Use [`xltabular`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular). It defines an environment `xltabular` that - according to the manual and unlike the `tabularx` environment after importing `ltablex` - behaves the same way as `tabularx`. In particular, you can use `itemize` in a cell.

Comment: This is the best environment for tables I've tested so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use longtable package which is useful for long table contents and use command `\endhead` to repeat the heading of a table in every new page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=1.4cm,left=1.0cm,right=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    This document is a list of changes made according to the requests for both examiners. Texts in black are the requested items from examiners, while texts in \textcolor{blue}{blue} are the amened items. Pages refer to the page number on which these requested items are in both the original document and \textcolor{blue}{amended document}.\\
    \newline
    \newline
    %\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{ C{2cm} | L{16cm} }


    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Changes Required from Examiner A}} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \textbf{\textit{page}} & \textbf{\textit{Content}} \\\hline \endhead
    \hline

       i & A good English speaker should look at the title, the Abstract, and Introduction and eliminate any elementary mistakes of no/definite/indefinite article, subject/verb agreement.\\
    & \\
       \textcolor{blue}{i} & \textcolor{blue}{All grammar has been checked.} \\
       & \\
    \hline

    N/A & The candidate should consider all titles of sections that are uninformative to any other reader, such as 4.2 Test WaveFlume, 4.3 Test Fiel\_H5\_T10, 4.4 Test Field\_IHFOAM, 4.5 Test Field\_Extend, 4.6
    Test Field\_H2\_T20, 5.1 Test\_SHORELINE. They are all meaningless, except to the person who has
    done the work. I strongly suggest something like “Flat bed, single water layer", "Flat bed, water
    layer and air layer", and so on.   \\
    & \\
     \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:}\\
   & 3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , \\
   & 3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,\\
   & 3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,\\
   & 3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,\\
   & 3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , \\
   & 4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,\\
   & 4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , \\
   & 4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,\\
   & 4.2.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,\\
   & 4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,\\
   & 4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity. \\
    & \\   
    \hline    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \hline
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    
       \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{All titles have been changed accordingly as follows:}\\
   & 3.1 Laboratory Flat Bed Wave Flume Test , \\
   & 3.2 Field Scale Flat Bed Test ,\\
   & 3.3 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using IHFOAM ,\\
   & 3.4 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using FoamExtend ,\\
   & 3.5 Field Scale Flat Bed Test using Different Wave Parameters , \\
   & 4 Continental Shelf Scale Simulation Series ,\\
   & 4.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Constant Slope , \\
   & 4.2 Continental Shelf Scale Test Validation  ,\\
   & 4.2.1 Continental Shelf Scale Test with A Varying Cell Thickness in Wave Propagating
    Direction ,\\
   & 4.2.2 Flat Bed Continental Shelf Scale Test ,\\
   & 4.2.3 Continental Shelf Scale Test with Fluid Viscosity. \\
    & \\   
    \hline    
      N/A & The candidate should insert dimensionless wave parameters wherever a wave is described, e.g. 1
    m, 10 s waves. I would prefer using wavelength, such as using values of $H/L$ and $L/d$, but the
    candidate might prefer to use $gT^2$ as a length scale. I always find it not very informative, and it is ambiguous anyway, as $T$ depends on wave speed.  \\
    & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{N/A} & \textcolor{blue}{Dimensionless terms have been included throughout the report, with an additional table, Table 3.3, summarises all wave parameters and relevant dimensionless terms used in the report.}\\ 
    & \\
    \hline
     38 & Referring to the examiner’s comment above about the outdated Figure 4.9, one could say that
    including it was redundant and the candidate might have shown more critical sense.
    The candidate could remove Figure 4.9 from the thesis. If that is not done, at least he should correct
    cnodial to cnoidal in two places in the caption.\\
     & \\
    \textcolor{blue}{37 - 39} & \textcolor{blue}{Figure 4.9 is removed, while additional information is added to make to conclusion with more critical thoughts.}\\    

    \end{longtable}

     %\end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Page no. 1 output

[image]

Page no. 2 output

[image]