# Adjusting Latex table width & length. Splitting table to multiple pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, tabularx

I am latex beginner.If I use tabularx, I am unable to split tables to multiple pages.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Summarized Analysis of Structured, OO, ADL \& WSO Approach}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline 
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{table:Summarized_Analysis_of_Structured_OO_ADL_WSO_Approach}
\end{table}
```

Comment: check this also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376790/tabularx-break-long-tables-over-several-pages

Comment: `xltabular`, `ltxtable`, and `ltablex` combine the features of `tabularx`(`X` type columns) with `longtable`(multiple page tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one possibility is to use

```
\usepackage{xltabular}
```

to be able to use a combination of package `longtable` and `tabularx`.

Then it is important that you have to redefine the header and footer of the
table for the different pages like this:

```
  \caption{Summarized Analysis of Structured, OO, ADL \& WSO Approach}%
  \label{table:Summarized_Analysis_of_Structured_OO_ADL_WSO_Approach}\\ 
  \hline
  \textbf{Header 1} & hHeader 2. & Header 3  & Header 4  \\ 
  \hline 
\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \textbf{Header 1} & hHeader 2. & Header 3  & Header 4  \\ 
  \hline
\endhead
  \hline
\endfoot
```

and you start your table with

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
```

With the following complete mwe

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % <================ showframe to visualize typing area and margins
\usepackage{xltabular} % <==============================================


\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|} % <==========================
%\centering
  \caption{Summarized Analysis of Structured, OO, ADL \& WSO Approach}%
  \label{table:Summarized_Analysis_of_Structured_OO_ADL_WSO_Approach}\\ 
  \hline
  \textbf{Header 1} & hHeader 2. & Header 3  & Header 4  \\ 
  \hline 
\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \textbf{Header 1} & hHeader 2. & Header 3  & Header 4  \\ 
  \hline
\endhead
  \hline
\endfoot
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ \hline
\textbf{Complete \& Clear Requirements} & hjhjhjhjhjhj hjhjhjhjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj. & jhjhjhj hjhjhjhjh jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhjhj hjhjjjjhjh.  & 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \\ %\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

you get the result

[image: page 1]

for page 1 with an small white space at the end of page 1 (see red arrow 3) because the next row is longer than space is there available ... and page 2

[image: page 2]

You can also, if you need it, add an remark into the `\endhead` part that table is continued or in the `\endfoot` part add a remark table to be continued and the adding `\endlastfoot` without that remark ... It depends on your needs ...