# Table With Long Cell Contents Over Multiple Pages

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, multirow

I am using *tabularx* to create a very large description table, where the content of a lot of the cells is either quite long — spanning over more than one line — or requires an explicit new line. A quick example is the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}        % splits cells with text longer than the column width
\usepackage{makecell}        % to allow for a header to span over two lines

\newcolumntype{f}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}    % each of the columns has a defined static width
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{#1}}   % centering the headers

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Sample table}
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|f|s|t|} 

    \hline
    \heading{\textbf{\makecell{Short\\Column}}} & \heading{\textbf{Medium Column}}  & \heading{\textbf{Long Column}} \\ \hline
    
    Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
    Value       & Text      & This text is too long to fit in one line and is automatically split into three   \\ \hline
    Value       & Text      & - 0: Important \newline
                              - 1: instance \newline
                              - 2: where \newline
                              - 3: the lines \newline
                              - 4: are manually \newline
                              - 5: split \newline
                              - 6: into \newline
                              - 7: items        \\ \hline
    Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
    Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
    ...
    Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
    
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which then goes over the page height limit until it disappears in the end of the page (notice the page number in the middle of the table as well):

[image]

Is there a way to make a table like this span over multiple pages? The solutions that I found (e.g. [2014](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages), [2016](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376790/tabularx-break-long-tables-over-several-pages) and [2017](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages)) for problems similar to mine — using packages such as *longtable* and *ltablex*— don't work for some of the specifics of the table I already have. I have tried to adapt them to do so, but could not make it work.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You also have `xltabular` (which loads `ltablex`), but  be aware  that long tables can break across pages only at the end of a row.

Comment: If you have this long lists inside of a table cell, probably entirely switching to a nested list might be a better idea. With thie approach you can have pagebreaks wherever needed.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested @Bernard in his comment, you should

- not use float `table`, it prevent to break table over pages
- for table use `xltabular` package

Using any sort of long table you should be aware, that those tables can be split between pages only between their rows.

An example of your table is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}        % splits cells with text longer than the column width
\newcolumntype{f}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize\hsize=\linewidth}X}    % each of the columns has a defined static width
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize\hsize=\linewidth}X}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize\hsize=\linewidth}X}
\usepackage{makecell}        % to allow for a header to span over two lines
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|f|s|t|} 
\caption{Sample table}
\label{tab:longtable}   \\
    \hline
\thead{Short Column}   & \thead{Medium Column}   & \thead{Long Column}     \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Sample table (cont.)}\\
    \hline
\thead{Short Column}   & \thead{Medium Column}   & \thead{Long Column}     \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape{Continued on the next page}}           \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%   table body
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & This text is too long to fit in one line and is automatically split into three   \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & - 0: Important \newline
                          - 1: instance \newline
                          - 2: where \newline
                          - 3: the lines \newline
                          - 4: are manually \newline
                          - 5: split \newline
                          - 6: into \newline
                          - 7: items        \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
Value       & Text      & Text              \\ \hline
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do was there a zero score? Now +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, I don't know :-(. Thank you very much! :-)