# How to make text in a Table cell spanning over multiple pages

Tags: tables, tabularx

This is a clear question of  [this version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552901/table-with-long-cell-contents-over-multiple-pages), I want that red zone in the table to move smoothly to the next page [image: fig].

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}       
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcolumntype{f}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}    
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{#1}}   

\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\rhead{}%
\lhead{}%
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{\textit{Page \thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}} }%\thepage
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Sample table}
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|f|s|t|} 

    \hline
    \heading{\textbf{\makecell{Short\\Column}}} & \heading{\textbf{Medium Column}}  & \heading{\textbf{Long Column}} \\ \hline
    
ot yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: - The tables will be put side by side. - The tables will span multiple pages. - On each table,& \blindtext[1]      & ot yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: - The tables will be put side by side. - The tables will span multiple pages. - On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to                \\ \hline
    Value       & Text      & This text is too long to fit in one line and is automatically I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in he lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: - The tables will be put side by side. - The tables will span multiple pages. - On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all  a  split into three   \\ \hline
    Value       & Text      & have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: - The tables will be put side by side. - The tables will span multiple pages. - On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet  \newline
                             have n\newline
                              - 7: items        \\ \hline
    
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `longtable`

Comment: Please provide correct MWE. Your code is incorrect.

Comment: @user202729 I have tried longtable, what i want exactly is the cell's content to span pages not the whole cell.

Comment: @mmr  the MWE is working properly on my machine texlive 2020.

Comment: Contents of a cell can't be split across pages. Packages such as longtable and others can only add a pagebreak between table rows, not within them.

Comment: this is a fact, This post is for tabular, longtable, xtabular, tabularx ... package developers to work on this issue.

Comment: Okay, same question as [Longtable: page breaks within row possible? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78578/longtable-page-breaks-within-row-possible) , still no automatic answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned @user202729 in his comment, your table is to long that can be fit in one page, so you need to use some sort of long table, for example defined by package `xltabular`.

**Warning:** Any long table can be broken between pages only between rows and never in a row!

For better spacing text into cells it is advisable to use smaller font, for example `\footnotesize` but this is up to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,
                     leftmargin = *,
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     before     = \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},
                     after      = \end{minipage}
                     }

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.6\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}R
                                  |>{\hsize=0.9\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}R
                                  |>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}R|}
\caption{Sample table}
\label{tab:longtable}   \\
    \hline
\thead{Short\\Column}   & \thead{Medium\\ Column}   & \thead{Long\\ Column}     \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Sample table (cont.)}\\
    \hline
\thead{Short\\Column}   & \thead{Medium\\ Column}   & \thead{Long\\ Column}     \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape{Continued on the next page}}           \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%   table body
Not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows:
    \begin{tabitemize}
\item   The tables will be put side by side. 
\item   The tables will span multiple pages. 
\item   On each table,
    \end{tabitemize}
    & \blindtext[1]      
        &       \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   Not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows:
        \item   The tables will be put side by side. 
        \item   The tables will span multiple pages. 
        \item   On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}).
            \end{tabitemize}
         As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to                \\
    \hline
Value   
    & Text
        & This text is too long to fit in one line and is automatically I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in he lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: 
        \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   The tables will be put side by side. 
        \item   The tables will span multiple pages. 
        \item   On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). 
        \end{tabitemize}
        As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all  a  split into three   \\
    \hline
Value   
    & Text      
        & have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: - The tables will be put side by side. - The tables will span multiple pages. - On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet  \\
    \hline
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You may consider to use `tabularray` package and its `longtblr` table. Code is a bit shorter and simpler but result is (to my opinion) nicer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,
                     leftmargin = *,
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     before     = \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},
                     after      = \end{minipage}
                     }

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Sample table},
    label = {longtable},
                ]{rowhead=1,
                  hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {X[0.2,j] X[0.3,j] X[0.53,j]},
                     rows = {font=\footnotesize},
                   row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
                  measure = vbox
                  }
%   column headers
{Short Column}   &     {Medium Column}   &   {Long Column}     \\
%   table body
Not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows:
    \begin{tabitemize}
\item   The tables will be put side by side. 
\item   The tables will span multiple pages. 
\item   On each table,
    \end{tabitemize}
    & \blindtext[1]      
        &       \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   Not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows:
        \item   The tables will be put side by side. 
        \item   The tables will span multiple pages. 
        \item   On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}).
            \end{tabitemize}
         As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to                \\
Value   
    & Text
        & This text is too long to fit in one line and is automatically I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in he lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: 
        \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   The tables will be put side by side. 
        \item   The tables will span multiple pages. 
        \item   On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). 
        \end{tabitemize}
        As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all  a  split into three   \\
Value   
    & Text      
        & have not yet found the solution. The problem is the following: For a business report, the requirement is to report the data in two different tables as follows: - The tables will be put side by side. - The tables will span multiple pages. - On each table, one of the columns will have a wrapping content (e.g. defined as p{4cm}). As a consequence the lines of the two tables will not be aligned, so I cannot use a single table with the column doubled.I have looked in all previously related questions but I have not yet  \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you did a great job, but what I want exactly is the cell's content to span pages, not the whole cell by changing the font size.