# Combining tabularx and longtable through ltablex

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I am reading user generated data and am trying to automate the layout. I would like the tables to stretch the width of the page, hence the use of `tabularx`. Further there may be times when some tables need to be broken over two pages, hence I need `longtable`. Then there was a problem for which [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376804/11162) answer helped by leading me towards `ltablex`. But once again there is a problem.

The MWE below demonstrates my problem.

Using just `tabularx` everything looks nice, but switching to `ltablex` causes the short table to be short in width as shown below. [image]

Question: How can I have the best of both `tabularx` and `longtable`?

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{tabularx} % with this, everything is ok unless there is a table that stretches over two pages
\usepackage{ltablex} % with this, the first table doesn't stretch and is not left aligned

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrX}
  \hline
col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
  \hline
3 & 6 & short comment\\ 
   \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrX}
  \hline
col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
  \hline
3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabularx}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use the `xltabular` environment.

Comment: Indeed this seems to solve the problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
]{
  colspec = {rrX},
  rowhead = 1,
}
\hline
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
  3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\ 
\hline
\end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: -- is there a `rotate` option in `tabularray` for text in a single cell -- I could not find it in the documentation

Comment: There is no `rotate` option at this time, but it is in the todo list: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/98

Answer (score 0):

Solution with use of the `tabularray`packageis very elegant(+1), but your problem can be solved also with insertion of `\keepXColumns` in preamble of your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\keepXColumns  % <----

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrX}
  \hline
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  \hline
3 & 6 & short comment\\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrX}
  \hline
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  \hline
3 & 6 & some long comment that should stretch to at least the edge of the page so that it wraps back to a second line. \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Above MWE produce

[image]